# Android Studio OnClick just working once

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

when I try to push the button it only works once...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView txt;
Button btn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            txt.setText("" +1);

        }
    } );
```

how can I solve it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you trying to do is this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView txt;
Button btn;
private int mCounter = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            txt.setText("" + mcounter++);

        }
    } );
```

Now when you click on the button the text will be 0 on the first time and then counting up every time you click the button. The problem with your code is, that it is no arithmetic operation, so the onclickmethod is called every time, but you have the same text every time too

Answer (score 1):

It works properly. Each your click sets **the same** text, so you can't see any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems OK.

You can add debug `log` or show a `toast` message to know the `button` click `status`.

**Try this:**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){

        txt.setText("" + 1);

        // Log
        Log.d("TEST", "Button clicked!");

        // Toast
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
} );
```

**If you want to show incremental value on `TextView`. Try this:**

```
// Initial value
final int count = 1;

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){

        txt.setText(String.valueOf(count));

        // Increment
        count++
    }
} );
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: No reason for that. Only his arithemtic operation is wrong.